# Connect to local MySQL Workbench DB via sqlplus

Tags: mysql, plsql, localhost, mysql-workbench, sqlplus

I'm trying to learn PL/SQL language. On my mac laptop (macOS Monterey, M1) I have the following set up:

MySQL Workbench running a test database

and SQL*Plus installed in the terminal

**My question:** How do I connect to my local MySQL Workbench database via sqlplus?

I imagine I need a user/pass and to specify localhost 3306 as the connection endpoint... but where do I find these things, how do I set them up? I've looked at Oracle documentation but haven't found the answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! This is study for a SQL interview. Thanks in advance.
-Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to use MySQL Workbench as a client for MySQL Server, or else you need to use SQL*Plus as a client for Oracle Server. These are two different brands of database (although they are both owned by Oracle Corporation) and the clients cannot connect to each other's database.

Your statement of connecting to MySQL Workbench using SQL*Plus makes no sense anyway, since both of these are clients.